# What is a proper way of implementing a server-side domain-scope global variable in a Vue.js application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js while trying to write an app that will need server-side state machine objects(to share some resources between clients and distribute client tasks to them). For this, I need some (domain-wide or at least process-scope)global variables such that **a client writes to it, another client can see it** by requesting something. But I'm going to need this on http requests.

I guess code-behind part is main.js, with `nano main.js` this is the environment:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

This doesn't look like multithread-ing. Does the `new` mean that each client creates a new instance or is it just one instance and it serves all clients? Should I use "global" variables in this scope or somewhere else in `App` object? In src folder, there is router folder but no App folder but a file App.vue. This file includes a script

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

Am I supposed to use only local(per client) variables here or any global is allowed too?

I added a variable in main.js as "myGlobal" as

```
...
import router from './router'
var myGlobal = 3.14;
...
```

and on client side

```
 console.log({{myGlobal}});
```

returns an error on building phase.

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token (158:21)

> 158 |         console.log({{myGlobal}});
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You can define globals wherever you want / need them. You can ofcourse import them (create a global.js that exports your globals) and import them wherever you need them. console.log({{myGlobal}}) will not work as you don't access myGlobal with the brackets - you only use them when working with templates.

Comment: Will other clients see the change if a client makes a new global (by some http request, for example)?

Comment: `window.myGlobal = 3.14;`

Comment: By global, I've meant, server-side global variable, that spans whole domain. For example, "number of popcorns left: 3", another client requests 1 popcorn, now all other clients will see "2". Without using a database, hdd or anything. Just a variable in RAM.

Comment: That's what you use state management (a.k.a. *store*) for.

Comment: @connexo Thank you, is it a module of App.js, I will google for then. What if I need to accumulate all http requests before processing them? Can I store http requests too, to respond back later such as 50-100 seconds later? I also need to merge multiple requests into one, if they come from same client.

Comment: For example, if server can serve 5 clients concurrently and if 6th connects, I should be able to postpone its http request in a queue, in a FIFO way. Can store/state management work with http requests themselves?